# Experience Profile No Search Results

Tags: experience-profile

I am running Sitecore 9 update 2 on Azure Web App, with Azure Search. I can see Profile data when I open Experience Profile, but when I try and search for any contact I get no results? (I know there are results)

I have tried making sure that the filters are applied correctly on the search, which they are. There are no errors in the logs, or in the browser.

I have noticed that I don't see an INFO log for my Search, like you'd see when you open Experience Profile i.e:

> 11096 17:10:10 INFO  [Experience Analytics]: Request:
>   [myDomain]/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/799B0CD6A8114772BDC46DC607106A62/all?&dateGrouping=by-week&&keyTop=5&keyOrderBy=visits-Asc&dateFrom=13-11-2018&dateTo=13-02-2019&keyGrouping=by-key
>   returned messages

[image]

I thought perhaps it could be that I needed to Rebuild the xDB index in Azure Search, that completed successfully, but still the issue persists.

Comment: I think raise a support ticket, there's been a lot of bugs with experience profile in 9.0.x

Comment: Did you rebuild the xDB search index AFTER you enabled searching of PII? Also do you have identified contacts or just anonymous contact?

Comment: Also by default the EP search are case sensitive. Try both cases.

Comment: Yeah I rebuilt the index afterwards. We only have identified contacts, not anonymous

Comment: @LeeSwainsbury did you check this one? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html

Answer (score 4):

[Enabling indexing of PII sensitive fields](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-pii-sensitive-data.html) is one way to fix this I've found, although it is of course up to your organization if you really want to use this fix.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work in my instance. So still working with Sitecore support to get to the bottom of it